# Purecss Roadmap and Project Status

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css, pure-css

Does anybody know the project status of the Purecss framework? From their blog and github it appears to be a dead project.

Answer (score 2):

It's alive, but in ownership transition. The most recent discussion is on Github https://github.com/yahoo/pure/issues/557. I'm helping to get the pieces in place to transition it properly.